# Ejb 2.1 migration

Tags: java, microservices, ejb-2.x

What is the best way to migrate the application which has EJB 2.1 implemenation.
This is highly critical application with more number of transactions we have used the stateless session beans/transaction type is container.
1. Should we migrate it to microservices architecture?
2. Migrate to the latest EJB version?
or any other option which provides flexible client integration.

Comment: it depends a lot your needs. it's good to search for a good forum.

Comment: some tips: Rest API. microservices seems to be a good choice, but it is expensive, you'll need to study a lot before taking a decision.

Comment: Yes right It totally depends on the need of the project. just like to clarify use microservices will be expensive in terms of infrastructure?

Comment: Yes. But, I'm not a specialist. My knowledge is basic. It's very good for you to study a lot about this, there are many articles on the internet.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestion!.